# mvc action invalid arguments gives argumentexception 500 instead of 404

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

When i have a controller action like this.

```
public ActionResult _Files(long parentid)
        {
```

if you call the action from a browser without a parentid. It throws a System.ArgumentException and a 500 response

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter
>   'parentid' of non-nullable type 'System.Int64' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult _Files

The action is NOT supposed to be called without a PARENTID by design. Is there a way to not throw an exception (and return 500 response back) and instead return a 400 bad request or a 404 not found ( either of which would make more sense IMO). Looking for a solution that would do this in a generic way across the webapplication ?

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you take a look at route constraints.  Creating a route constraint would require an integer to be passed as the parentid and if not supplied, the route will not match and a 404 will be returned by default.

Here's an example:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "MyController",
    url: "MyController/{parentid}",
    defaults: new { controller = "MyController", action = "Index" },
    constraints: new { parentid = @"\d+" }
);
```

See this article for more information on [route constraints](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs).

The only downside to this approach is that the regex does not check whether the input value is a `long` or something greater.  However if that were a concern, you could easily create a custom route constraint that would check whether the input value could be parsed as a `long`.

Comment: this would have to be done for every action .. which is not what i want. As we have 100s of actions.

Answer (score 3):

Reference: http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/5/exception_handling_in_asp_net_mvc

**Create an Error Controller Class and corresponding views:**

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult NotFound()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

**in Global.asax.cs:**

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var httpContext = ((MvcApplication)sender).Context;
    var currentController = " ";
    var currentAction = " ";
    var currentRouteData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext));
    if (currentRouteData != null)
    {
        if (currentRouteData.Values["controller"] != null && 
            !String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentRouteData.Values["controller"].ToString()))
        {
            currentController = currentRouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
        }
        if (currentRouteData.Values["action"] != null && 
            !String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentRouteData.Values["action"].ToString()))
        {
            currentAction = currentRouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
        }
    }
    var ex = Server.GetLastError();
    var controller = new ErrorController();
    var routeData = new RouteData();
    var action = "Index";
    var statusCode = 500;
    if (ex is ArgumentException)
    {
        action = "NotFound";
        statusCode = 404;
    }
    httpContext.ClearError();
    httpContext.Response.Clear();
    httpContext.Response.StatusCode = statusCode;             
    httpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
    routeData.Values["controller"] = "Error";
    routeData.Values["action"] = action;
    controller.ViewData.Model = new HandleErrorInfo(ex, currentController, currentAction);
    ((IController)controller).Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext), routeData));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

what you can do is following:

```
    public ActionResult _Files(long  ? parentid)
    {
```

parentId is nullable.

Then in your action, you need to handle it as follows:

```
    public ActionResult _Files(long  ? parentid)
    {
      if(parentId.HasValue == false) {return some http status code;}
      // Then you can use parentId with its Value property.
```

Comment: @DavidHaney yeah that s what i meant.

Comment: like i said looking to have a solution which spans the application. By design parentid should not be null. And i will have to do this in the 100's of actions i have, which accepts longs or ints by design!

Comment: There is no such solution. You can use Route Attributes. But they dont cover this. You should be defensive all the time.